# How can I remove blank pages from rbookdown pdfs?

Tags: latex, knitr, bookdown

I am using the default Bookdown example "A Minimal Book Example" which is available on GitHub: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo

How do I edit the template so that the PDF output does not have blank pages before all the chapters?

I don't speak TeX so basic clues for the clueless would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not a problem with rbookdown itself, but it is because of a classoption in the documentclass "book" in LaTex. I found the hint [here](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/299).

At the top of you index.Rmd file, you have `documentclass: book` in your YAML header. Right below it, add `classoption: openany` to fix this. For example:

```
--- 
title: "Fancy Title"
author: "Your Name"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
documentclass: book
classoption: openany
---
```